# Logic to check to see if multiple imgs pop ups have been clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

So I wanted to create this concept of a simple game where imgs are loaded onto a screen and alert pop ups for each one,sort of like find an object game. I have that part done but I wanted to create an instance of a conditional statement that checks to see if the image was clicked.

When all elements have been clicked I was going to incorporate a pop up stating that the user has clicked everything on the page?Help please!

```
 <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And what JavaScript are you using?

Comment: I was using the bootstrap built in js funtionality. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/. Ive only written the alert funtionality for each img

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should get you started:

```js
//$('body').css('background','blue');
var arrBoxes = [];
var ttl = $('.mybox').length;
$('.mybox').click(function(){
   var bx = this.id;
   if (arrBoxes.indexOf(bx) >= 0){
     alert('already clicked');
   }else{
     arrBoxes.push(bx);
   }
   if (arrBoxes.length == ttl) alert('all done');
});
```

```css
.mybox{float:left;width:150px;height:150px;margin:10px;}
.modal-body{overflow:auto;} /* Fixes float:left */
#b1{background:palegreen;}
#b2{background:wheat;}
#b3{background:pink;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
 Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <div id="b1" class="mybox">Box One</div>
         <div id="b2" class="mybox">Box Two</div>
         <div id="b3" class="mybox">Box Three</div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind! thank you!. I'm fairly new to jquery as well but I referenced I think correctly,but it doesn't work.Everything goes within the head tag with the jquery cdn first then the actually code? sorry for being a noob

Comment: I added another answer to explain this. *Best wishes with your project.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of these three sample layouts. They are listed in order of popularity, with most popular at top. However, they all work just fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta tags go here>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mycode.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- HTML CODE IN HERE -->
    </body>
</html>
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta tags go here>
        <style>
            /*  Style code in here */
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://CDN/jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                /*  jQuery code in here */
            }); //END document.ready
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- HTML CODE IN HERE -->
    </body>
</html>
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta tags go here>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- HTML CODE IN HERE -->
        <style>
            /*  Style code in here */
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://CDN/jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                /*  jQuery code in here */
            }); //END document.ready
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

If you use the first method, then you would also create these external files:

```
 public_html/css/common.css
 public_html/js/jquery.min.js <--- downloaded from jQuery web site
 public_html/js/myscripts.js
```

For the CSS document, you just take the code from between the `<style></style>` tags and save it into that external file.

For the jQuery document, you just take the code from between the `<script></script>` tags and save it into that external file.

*Above, note that `public_html` is whatever your webroot is. If you purchase online shared hosting from GoDaddy or HostGator etc., it will usually be `public_html`. If you install XAMPP locally, it will be `htdocs`. If WAMP or MAMP, it will be `www`.*